# rvest the gender given names

Tags: r, rvest

I'm trying to ha`rvest` gender for a list of about 1,000 unique `names` using this cute little function:

**EDIT:** function updated to return the gender directly. based on @Ronak Shah output below I realized it was not accurate (i.e., `Greg => Female`)

```
 gender_from_name <- function(name){
      name_url <- paste("https://nameberry.com/babyname/",  name, sep = "")
      is_it_a_boy <- read_html(name_url) %>% 
        html_nodes("span.meta-section span a") %>% 
        html_text(trim=TRUE)
      return (is_it_a_boy)
      }
```

However, the code trips when url does not exist for a name such as `Håkan`

for instance:

```
 names <- data.frame(c("Grant", "Greg", "Gregory", "Guillaume", "Guy", "Gwen", "Gyuri", "Håkan"))
    gender <- apply(names,1, gender_from_name)
```

producing  `Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 400.`  is there a way to suppress it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tryCatch` to capture the error and return `NA` for url's which don't exist.

```
library(rvest)

gender_from_name <- function(name){

  name_url <- paste("https://nameberry.com/babyname/",  name, sep = "")
  is_it_a_boy <- tryCatch({
    read_html(name_url) %>% 
    html_nodes(".girl") %>% 
    html_text(trim=TRUE) %>% 
    length() == 0}, error = function(e) return(NA))
  if(is.na(is_it_a_boy)) return(NA)
  
  return (if(is_it_a_boy) "Male" else "Female")
}

sapply(names$name, gender_from_name)
#    Grant      Greg   Gregory Guillaume       Guy      Gwen     Gyuri   Håkan 
#  "Female"  "Female"  "Female"  "Female"  "Female"  "Female"  "Female"     NA
```

**data**

```
names <- data.frame(name = c("Grant", "Greg", "Gregory", "Guillaume", 
                             "Guy", "Gwen", "Gyuri", "Håkan"))
```